# How can a matrix represent a relation when a relation is not a function?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix can represent a relation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix). How is this so? Since matrices are a representation of linear maps, does this mean that a linear map is not necessarily a function?

Comment: the linear map represented by the matrix is not the same as the relation

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the important thing is to have a bijection between the set of all binary relations on sets X,Y and linear maps represented by |X|x|Y| matrices, right? In general, if i think of any way to map any entity like for example connections in a graph to a matrix (incidence matrix), then automatically I have a bijection between the set of those entities and linear maps represented by all mxn matrices and can use linear algebra to study those entities?

Answer (score 3):

Don’t confuse the representation with the thing being represented. A PNG image might show a portrait of person, or a rendered math equation. Both are grids of pixels but that doesn’t mean that human faces are types of math equations (or vice versa).

Similarly a matrix is just a rectangular grid of numbers. Linear maps can be expressed using matrices, but so can many other, unrelated, things. Binary relations can be expressed as a matrix of 0s and 1s, and this representation is fruitful since it lets us express new ideas (composition of relations) in terms of old ones (matrix multiplication). But a matrix of numbers might represent a linear map, or might represent a binary relation, and the two are *not* the same.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the important thing is to have a bijection between the set of all binary relations on sets X,Y and linear maps represented by |X|x|Y| matrices, right? In general, if i think of any way to map any entity like for example connections in a graph to a matrix (incidence matrix), then automatically I have a bijection between the set of those entities and linear maps represented by all mxn matrices and can use linear algebra to study those entities?